# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Student.addHomework(Grades.java:42) at Grades.main(Grades.java:198)

Tags: java, exception

I know this question has been asked/answered before but in my case I have no idea where the null would be.

Code:

```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Scanner;

    // An abstraction for a student.
    class Student implements Comparable<Student>
    {
private String fname;      // first name
private String lname;      // last name
private double[] homework; // homework scores (each out of 100)
private double[] project;  // project scores (each out of 100)
private double[] exam;     // exam scores (each out of 100)

// Returns the sum of the elements in the array x.
private double sum(double[] x)
{
    // TBD
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; x.length >= i; i++)
    {
        double j = x[i];
        sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
}

// Construct a Student object given the first and last name.
public Student(String fname, String lname)
{
    // TBD: initialize attributes fname and lname to the arguments; initialize 
    // homework, project, and exam to arrays of sizes 6, 2, and 3 respectively.
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    double[] homework = new double[6];
    double[] project = new double[2];
    double[] exam = new double[3]; 
}

// Sets ith homework score for this student.
public void addHomework(int i, double score)
{
    // TBD
    homework[i] = score;       
}

// Sets ith project score for this student.
public void addProject(int i, double score)
{
    // TBD
    project[i] = score;
}

// Sets ith exam score for this student.
public void addExam(int i, double score)
{
    // TBD
    exam[i] = score;
}

// Calculates and returns the overall percent score (weighted 
// appropriately) for this student. Scores are weighted as 5% 
// for homework, 20% for projects, and 75% for the exams.
public double overallScore()
{
    // TBD
    int i;
    double hScore = 0;
    double pScore = 0;
    double eScore = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= homework.length; i++)
    {
        hScore += homework[i];            
    }
    double Thscore = hScore/homework.length;
    for(i = 0; i <= project.length; i++)
    {
        pScore += project[i];            
    }
    double Tpscore = pScore/project.length;
    for(i = 0; i <= exam.length; i++)
    {
        eScore += exam[i];            
    }
    double Tescore = eScore/exam.length;
    double overallScore = (.05*Thscore) + (.20*Tpscore) + (.75*Tescore);
    return overallScore;
}

// Returns the overall letter grade for this student.
//
// Score     Grade
// [90, 100] A   
// [85, 90)  A-  
// [80, 85)  B\+ 
// [75, 80)  B   
// [70, 75)  B-  
// [65, 70)  C\+     
// [60, 65)  C   
// [55, 60)  C-  
// [50, 55)  D\+ 
// [45, 50)  D   
// [40, 45)  D-  
// [0, 40)   F   
public String overallGrade()
{
    // TBD
    final double score = this.overallScore();
    final String grade;

    if (score > 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
    }
    else if (score > 85)
    {
        grade = "A-";
    }
    else if (score > 80)
    {
        grade = "B or B+";
    }
    else if (score > 75)
    {
        grade = "B";
    }
    else if (score > 70)
    {
        grade = "B-";
    }
    else if (score > 65)
    {
        grade = "C or C+";
    }
    else if (score > 60)
    {
        grade = "C";
    }
    else if (score > 55)
    {
        grade = "C-";
    }
    else if (score > 50)
    {
        grade = "D or D+";
    }
    else if (score > 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
    }
    else if (score > 40)
    {
        grade = "D-";
    }
    else
    {
        grade = "F";
    }
    return grade;
}

// Compares this student to that according to overall score.
public int compareTo(Student that)
{
    // TBD        
    return (this.overallScore() > that.overallScore()) ? 1 : 
        (this.overallScore() < that.overallScore()) ? -1 : 0;
}

// Returns a string representation of this student in the format 
// "fname lname | overall score | grade". For example, 
// "Albert Einstein | 95.5 | A".
public String toString()
{
    // TBD
    return fname + " " + lname + " | " + overallScore() + " | " + overallGrade();
}
   }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                               //
    //               DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW                    //
    //                                                               //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Reads the scores for the n (command-line argument) students from STDIN 
    // and prints their names, overall score, and grade in reverse order 
    // of overall score.
    public class Grades
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
Student[] students = new Student[n];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String fname = scan.next();
    String lname = scan.next();
    Student student = new Student(fname, lname);
        student.addHomework(0, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addHomework(1, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addHomework(2, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addHomework(3, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addHomework(4, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addHomework(5, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addProject(0, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addProject(1, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addExam(0, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addExam(1, scan.nextDouble());
        student.addExam(2, scan.nextDouble());
    students[i] = student;
}
Arrays.sort(students);
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
   }
```

Then I compile/run it with the set of scores given to me ($ java Grades 41 > scores.txt) and get the error as mentioned.

Any help. It won't help me in time to submit this but knowing the problem will help me code further down the line

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception occurs at following line in `Student` class:

```
    homework[i] = score;
```

This is because in `Student` constructor, instead of initializing the instance variable `homework` you are creating a local variable `homework` and initializing it. Since, `addHomeWork` method uses the instance variable, while assigning value to `homework` null pointer exception is thrown.

```
public Student(String fname, String lname)
{
    // TBD: initialize attributes fname and lname to the arguments; initialize 
    // homework, project, and exam to arrays of sizes 6, 2, and 3 respectively.
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    double[] homework = new double[6]; //<--ERROR, Creating local variable
    double[] project = new double[2];  //<--ERROR, Creating local variable
    double[] exam = new double[3];     //<--ERROR, Creating local variable
}
```

Also, in your code there are few conditional mistakes made in loops used in method `overallScore`.

`for(i = 0; i <= homework.length; i++)` needs to be replaced with

`for(i = 0; i < homework.length; i++)` as the iteration begins at zero.

Following is the updated code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

// An abstraction for a student.
class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
    private String fname;      // first name
    private String lname;      // last name
    private double[] homework; // homework scores (each out of 100)
    private double[] project;  // project scores (each out of 100)
    private double[] exam;     // exam scores (each out of 100)

    //Returns the sum of the elements in the array x.
    private double sum(double[] x)
    {
        // TBD
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; x.length >= i; i++)
        {
            double j = x[i];
            sum += j;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    //Construct a Student object given the first and last name.
    public Student(String fname, String lname)
    {
        // TBD: initialize attributes fname and lname to the arguments; initialize 
        // homework, project, and exam to arrays of sizes 6, 2, and 3 respectively.
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        homework = new double[6];
        project = new double[2];
        exam = new double[3]; 
    }

    //Sets ith homework score for this student.
    public void addHomework(int i, double score)
    {
        // TBD
        homework[i] = score;       
    }

    //Sets ith project score for this student.
    public void addProject(int i, double score)
    {
        // TBD
        project[i] = score;
    }

    //Sets ith exam score for this student.
    public void addExam(int i, double score)
    {
        // TBD
        exam[i] = score;
    }

    //Calculates and returns the overall percent score (weighted 
    //appropriately) for this student. Scores are weighted as 5% 
    //for homework, 20% for projects, and 75% for the exams.
    public double overallScore()
    {
        // TBD
        int i;
        double hScore = 0;
        double pScore = 0;
        double eScore = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < homework.length; i++)
        {
            hScore += homework[i];            
        }
        double Thscore = hScore/homework.length;
        for(i = 0; i < project.length; i++)
        {
            pScore += project[i];            
        }
        double Tpscore = pScore/project.length;
        for(i = 0; i < exam.length; i++)
        {
            eScore += exam[i];            
        }
        double Tescore = eScore/exam.length;
        double overallScore = (.05*Thscore) + (.20*Tpscore) + (.75*Tescore);
        return overallScore;
    }

    //Returns the overall letter grade for this student.
    //
    //Score     Grade
    //[90, 100] A   
    //[85, 90)  A-  
    //[80, 85)  B\+ 
    //[75, 80)  B   
    //[70, 75)  B-  
    //[65, 70)  C\+     
    //[60, 65)  C   
    //[55, 60)  C-  
    //[50, 55)  D\+ 
    //[45, 50)  D   
    //[40, 45)  D-  
    //[0, 40)   F   
    public String overallGrade()
    {
        // TBD
        final double score = this.overallScore();
        final String grade;

        if (score > 90)
        {
            grade = "A";
        }
        else if (score > 85)
        {
            grade = "A-";
        }
        else if (score > 80)
        {
            grade = "B or B+";
        }
        else if (score > 75)
        {
            grade = "B";
        }
        else if (score > 70)
        {
            grade = "B-";
        }
        else if (score > 65)
        {
            grade = "C or C+";
        }
        else if (score > 60)
        {
            grade = "C";
        }
        else if (score > 55)
        {
            grade = "C-";
        }
        else if (score > 50)
        {
            grade = "D or D+";
        }
        else if (score > 45)
        {
            grade = "D";
        }
        else if (score > 40)
        {
            grade = "D-";
        }
        else
        {
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;
    }

    //Compares this student to that according to overall score.
    public int compareTo(Student that)
    {
        // TBD        
        return (this.overallScore() > that.overallScore()) ? 1 : 
            (this.overallScore() < that.overallScore()) ? -1 : 0;
    }

    //Returns a string representation of this student in the format 
    //"fname lname | overall score | grade". For example, 
    //"Albert Einstein | 95.5 | A".
    public String toString()
    {
        // TBD
        return fname + " " + lname + " | " + overallScore() + " | " 
               + overallGrade();
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                               //
//               DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW                    //
//                                                               //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Reads the scores for the n (command-line argument) students from STDIN 
// and prints their names, overall score, and grade in reverse order 
// of overall score.
public class Grades
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        Student[] students = new Student[n];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String fname = scan.next();
            String lname = scan.next();
            Student student = new Student(fname, lname);
            student.addHomework(0, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addHomework(1, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addHomework(2, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addHomework(3, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addHomework(4, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addHomework(5, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addProject(0, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addProject(1, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addExam(0, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addExam(1, scan.nextDouble());
            student.addExam(2, scan.nextDouble());
            students[i] = student;
        }
        Arrays.sort(students);
        for (Student s : students) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```